# How to name this data structure

Tags: c#, sql, database, data-structures

I have this class in C#

1.A private DataTable. This datatable is initialized by a database query.

2.get(string filter) method, this method do DataTable.select(filter) on the private DataTable. And throw exception if it found 0 or more than 1 rows. Otherwise, it return the only row that it found.

I couldn't think of a proper name for it. Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UniqueRowSelector` or `SingleRowSelector`? Because it can only return one row.

Answer (score 1):

getSingleRowByName

Replace "Name" with whatever the string parameter is representative of.

Answer (score 0):

i think `DatabaseTable` describes it pretty well